# Linked list queries

Tags: c, data-structures

I have this singly linked list:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
struct list_el {
   int val;
   struct list_el * next;
};

typedef struct list_el item;

int main() {
   item * curr, * head;
   int i, num_nodes;

   head = NULL;
   printf("Enter the number of nodes to be created: ");
   scanf("%d", &num_nodes);
   for(i=1;i<=num_nodes;i++) {
      curr = (item *)malloc(sizeof(item));
      printf("\n Enter the value :");
      scanf("%d", &curr->val);
      curr->next  = head;
      head = curr;
   }

   curr = head;

   while(curr) {
      printf("%d --> ", curr->val);
      curr = curr->next ;
   }
   getch();
   return 0;
}
```

What does the line urr = head; mean?
Also, while printing, if prints the linked list in reverse. Why is it so? I think it is because we are assigning the last node as curr with the above statement? If yes, how the curr->next work insid ethe while (curr) loop?

Comment: Step through the code, line by line, to see what it really does (if you can't understand this very simple code). Or better yet, try to do it on paper first!

Comment: From where have you copied the code?

Answer (score 3):

In order of questions asked:

> What does `curr = head;` mean?

It means take the address held in the pointer-variable `head` and store it in the pointer variable `curr`. It is not different than copying by-value any other type, such as `int a=1, b; b=a;`

> (It) prints the linked list in reverse. Why is it so?

As you're adding each new item, that new item becomes the list head. therefore if you enter the numbers in a specific order, the *last* one will be the first one in the list, and the first will be the last. This type of structure is commonly called a LIFO (Last-In-First-Out).

---

If you want the list to actually be in the order entered *without scanning to the end of the list with each new insertion* this is one way to do it (and imho, the most efficient):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct list_el
{
    int val;
    struct list_el * next;
};
typedef struct list_el item;

int main()
{
    item *curr, *head = NULL, **pp = &head;
    int i, num_nodes;

    printf("Enter the number of nodes to be created: ");
    scanf("%d", &num_nodes);

    for(i=1;i<=num_nodes;i++)
    {
        *pp =  malloc(sizeof(**pp)); // note: don't cast malloc() in C
        if (*pp == NULL)
        {
            perror("Failed to allocate node");
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }

        printf("\n Enter the value :");
        scanf("%d", &(*pp)->val);
        pp = &(*pp)->next;
    }

    // terminate the list
    *pp = NULL;

    // walk the list
    curr = head;
    while(curr)
    {
        printf("%d --> ", curr->val);
        curr = curr->next ;
    }
    getch();
    return 0;
}
```

**How It Works**

A pointer-to-pointer, `pp`, is used to always hold the *address* of the pointer that will receive the next new node allocation. Initially it starts with the address of the `head` pointer variable. As each new node is inserted `pp` is loaded with the address of the `next` member of that added node. When the loop is finished, it will point to the *last* `next` pointer in the list, so we set it to NULL to terminate, and we're finished.

Note that with this algorithm a special `if (first-node)` check is *not* needed with each iteration. The head pointer naturally fills in with the first node added (or is set to NULL if *no* nodes are added).

Finally, I left most of the (lack of) error checking for you to address, though I had to add the `malloc()` result check, from force of habit if nothing else. You should be checking the success of each library call made in this, particularly the `scanf()` calls

**Input**

```
Enter the number of nodes to be created: 5

 Enter the value :1

 Enter the value :2

 Enter the value :3

 Enter the value :4

 Enter the value :5
```

**Output**

```
1 --> 2 --> 3 --> 4 --> 5 -->
```

Answer (score 1):

`curr = head` means that your `curr` pointer will point to the same node as the `head` pointer does. Then you use `curr` as the iterator and run over the items in the list (in the `while` loop).

It prints in reverse because items are added at the beginning of the list in these lines :

```
curr->next  = head;
head = curr;
```

**EDIT :** Change the way you add items to the list so they will be added to the end of the list :

```
 item *tempPointer = NULL;
 for(i=1;i<=num_nodes;i++) {
      curr = (item *)calloc(sizeof(item));         
      printf("\n Enter the value :");
      scanf("%d", &curr->val);
      if (i == 1) 
        head = curr;
      else {     
        tempPointer ->next  = curr;
      }      

      tempPointer = curr;
   }
```

Comment: How do I print it from beginning to end? Could you please help?